# Understanding「その半分を超える日数を職場での就業体験に充てたインターンシップを対象とします」

Tags: reading-comprehension

> 活用には一定の条件が必要で、具体的には、短期のものは5日間以上、専門性を踏まえた長期のものは2週間以上実施したうえで、**その半分を超える日数を職場での就業体験に充てたインターンシップを対象とします**。([source](https://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/html/20220614/k10013670431000.html))

I have difficulty understanding the overall meaning of this sentence, especially the bold part.

So once you reached first half of the work period (2.5 days for short term and 1 week for long term), it is as an internship? Internship is 対象 for what? As one of 一定の条件?

Also what does 専門性を踏まえた means before 長期のもの? Long term work that involves expertise?

Comment: Here's the background story: government was issuing subsidy to companies for babysitting the interns, because "fostering young talent" was the official primary public interest. Internship was not supposed to be meant for companies to do low-risk recruitment or public appeal. But this has changed. Now companies are further allowed to leverage the internship program as a means to discover and secure young resource (aka 青田買い).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to connect with the preceding paragraphs. 活用する could be a hint.

> 政府は、学生の就職活動をめぐって、「インターンシップ」のルールを見直し、一定期間、職場で就業体験を行うことなどを条件に、参加した学生の評価を、**企業が採用のために活用する**のを認めることになりました。
>
> 文部科学省、厚生労働省それに経済産業省は13日、インターンシップをめぐる3省の合意によるルールを見直し、来年度以降に行うインターンシップについて、参加した学生の情報を**企業が採用のための判断材料として活用する**のを認めることとしました。
>
> **活用**には一定の条件が必要で、具体的には、短期のものは5日間以上、専門性を踏まえた長期のものは2週間以上実施したうえで、その半分を超える日数を職場での就業体験に充てたインターンシップを対象とします。

The assumption is that internships can't (officially) be used as part of recruitment today. And the gov is changing the rule so that companies can do that.

- 活用には一定の条件が必要で = インターンシップを採用のために活用するには一定の条件が必要で : To use internship for recruitment requires a few conditions,

The rest explains the actual conditions. It must be certain days depending on the type (短期 or 長期) and more than half of the internship period must be spent on actually working in the office, shop etc. How long the OJT should be depend on the length of internship, if it is a short type and 6 days then at least 3 days must be OJT.

- 短期のものは5日間以上 the short internship is >5 days,
- 専門性を踏まえた長期のものは2週間以上実施したうえで : the long one which is based on expertise is >2 weeks

Here both もの are internship. 専門性を踏まえた literally means "based on expertise", which may be a bit unidiomatic (in English), but by context it means something like "assumes some expertise/experience" and refers to kind of internship that takes longer due to the training before joining the actual  internship project.

The その半分を超える日数を職場での就業体験に充てたインターンシップを対象とします connects with both 短期のものは... and 専門性を踏まえた.... That is, the sentence is a shorthand for

> 短期のものは5日間以上（**実施したうえでその半分を超える日数を職場での就業体験に充てたインターンシップを対象とし**）、専門性を踏まえた長期のものは2週間以上実施したうえで、その半分を超える日数を職場での就業体験に充てたインターンシップを対象とします

You can consider 対象とします as something like 新ルール適用の対象とします = those where the new rule applies.

Comment: As always, thank you for detailed answers! Maybe I'm missing context or something. I don't get what is meant by using/not using internship as part of recruitment process.

Comment: @JimmyYang I'm not exactly sure either, but I guess currently internship is internship, separated from recruitment. That is, if a former intern applies,  the assessment must follow the same procedure as other candidates. Now it is possible to make an offer to former interns who performed well with less interviews or skipping paper tests. [This](https://www.nikkei.com/article/DGXZQOUA1339L0T10C22A6000000/) seems less vague: これまで採用活動前の学生のインターン情報については「広報活動・採用選考活動に使用できない」と明記していたが、一定の条件を満たすインターンは活用できる方針を追記した。